# Неодружена чи незаміжня?

Tags: різниця-між-словами

[Сайт «Как правильно?»](//kak-pravilno.net/nezamizhnya-chi-neodruzhena-yak-pravilno/):

> **Правильно**
>
> *Незаміжня* — єдиний правильний варіант, походить від слова “заміжня” (рос. “за мужем”), заміжньою може бути тільки жінка.
>
> *Сімейний стан — незаміжня*
>   *Незаміжня жінка шукає роботу*
>
> **Неправильно**
>
> *Неодружена* — принципово невірний варіант, оскільки одруженим чи неодруженим може бути тільки чоловік (від слова “дружина”).

Але [сайт «ГОРОХ»](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9):

> *НЕОДРУ́ЖЕНИЙ* — який не перебуває в шлюбі.
>   [І жодного натяку про те, що це стосується виключно чоловічої статі — коментар мій.]

Значить можна вживати обидва слова?

Comment: Таке враження що сайт "как правильно" змінив статтю відповідно до відповідей на це питання тут. Зараз там обидва варіанти подаються як правильні.

Comment: Одруження - це процес державної реєстрації шлюбу, який засвідчується відповідним офіційним актом громадянського стану (Свідоцтво про шлюб). https://zakon.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/2947-14#Text

На відміну від Весілля (традиційного ритуалу святкування створення сім'ї), в наслідок укладення шлюбу відбувається зміна майнових прав учасників подружжя. Отже, офіційно "неодружений (неодружена)".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Іменка, що вже московською назвою, „Как правильно“ не надає остаточних підтверджень: наприклад відсутні значимі джерела. Я, як українець, котрий читав старі письмена і знаю инші словʼянські мови — там *дружина* переважно від слова *жінка*, точно знаю, що слова *одружений* і *дружина* походять від широкого слова з сенсом *дружити*. Тому [дружиною](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/14169-druzhyna.html) буває і [чоловік](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0), які б помітки, задля зменшення вживу, не ставив наступний совʼєтський словник.

[Словник української мови: в 11 томах. — Том 2, 1971. — Стор. 424.](http://sum.in.ua/s/druzhyna)

> **ДРУЖИНА**, **и**.
>
> **1.** *жін.* Одружена жінка стосовно до свого чоловіка.
>
> *Заколисаний родинним щастям з любою дружиною, Семен забув на свої колишні турботи* (Михайло Коцюбинський, I, 1955, 109); *Він узяв собі дружину, маленьку, кволу, але щиру до роботи жінку* (Степан Чорнобривець, Визволена земля, 1959, 42).
>
> **2.** *чол.*, *заст.*, *поет.* Одружений чоловік стосовно до своєї жінки.
>
> *Якби мені крила, крила Соколинії, Полетіла б я за милим, За дружиною* (Тарас Шевченко, II, 1953, 167); [Сербин:] *Не можу я стати тобі дружиною навік, бо коли ти і сама усе узнаєш, то не підеш зо мною* (Степан Васильченко, III, 1960, 33).
>
> **3.** жін. Група, загін, добровільне обʼєднання людей, створене з якою-небудь метою.
>
> *В Києві, Одесі, Миколаєві в грудневі дні [1905 р.] озброювались робітники, формувались бойові дружини* (Історія УРСР, I, 1953, 611); *В усіх кварталах міста створено санітарні дружини* (Василь Кучер, Чорноморці, 1956, 112); *З народної ініціативи виникли і користуються довір'ям такі нові форми участі трудящих у зміцненні порядку, як товариські суди та добровільні народні дружини* (Матеріали XXI з'їзду КПУ, 1960, 69).
>
> **4.** жін. У стародавній Русі — збройний загін, що становив постійну військову силу князя і брав участь в управлінні князівством.
>
> *Та ось, наче смерті яма, Відчинилась міська брама І з дружиною малою Вийшов князь з Переяслава* (Іван Франко, XIII, 1954, 369); *Велика воєнна здобич, що потрапляла до рук слов'янської знаті, збагачувала її і давала можливість утримувати добре озброєні дружини* (Історія СРСР, I, 1957, 26).

Також цїлком широковживане наступне слово

> **ПОДРУ́ЖЖЯ**, **я**, *сер*.
>
> **1.** Шлюбна пара; чоловік і дружина.
>
> *[Хуса:] В римлян то звичай, що коли подружжя приходить вкупі, то й вітати треба обох укупі* (Леся Українка, III, 1952, 152); *Це було істинно щасливе подружжя, вони були мовби створені одне для одного* (Олесь Гончар, Тронка, 1963, 301);
>
> * Образно. *Подружжя гусей підійшло до колодязя* (Остап Вишня, I, 1956, 346).
>
> **2.** Шлюбне життя, шлюб.
>
> *Вони були люди вже не молоді, мали в подружжі дітей* (Наталія Кобринська, Вибр., 1954, 110); *Подружжя виявилося напрочуд вдалим* (Вадим Собко, Біле полум'я, 1952, 25).
>
> **3.** Один із членів шлюбної пари; дружина щодо свого чоловіка або чоловік щодо своєї дружини.
>
> *Дядько Тимоха хоч пʼятий десяток год жив, а подружжя собі не знайшов* ([Борис](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/34819-odruzhuvaty.html) · [Грінченко](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/34820-odruzhuvatysja.html#show_point), I, 1963, 285); — *Тут.. нічого нашого не зосталося. — Нічого? А могила твого батька? Хай і мене коло нього поховають, — мимоволі подається [Катерина] в той бік, де, відробивши своє, лежить її подружжя* (Михайло Стельмах, I, 1962, 4).

Висновок цїлком очевидниь: **одружена — всецїло правильне слово**. А ось вживати *заміжня* — буде дещо, за лоґікою, застарілим, бо, нагадаю, основа слова — *[муж](http://sum.in.ua/s/muzh)* — архаїчне чи доволї книжне. Також відмічу непоганою статтею [„Супряжене“](//zbruc.eu/node/75573) пана [Юрія Андруховича](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87_%D0%AE%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%86%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87).

Answer (score 5):

Так, можна вживати обидва.

Сайт «Как правильно» в даному разі пише неправильно.

## Визначення з тлумачного словника

«Словник української мови» в 11 томах:

> [**НЕОДРУ́ЖЕНИЙ**](http://sum.in.ua/s/neodruzhenyj), а, е. Який не перебуває в шлюбі. <…>
>
> ---
>
> [**ОДРУ́ЖЕНИЙ**](http://sum.in.ua/s/odruzhenyj), а, е. Дієпр[икметник] пас[ивний] мин[улого] ч[асу] до **одружити**. <…>
>
> ---
>
> [**ОДРУЖИ́ТИ**](http://sum.in.ua/s/odruzhyty) *див[іться]* **одружувати**. <…>
>
> ---
>
> [**ОДРУ́ЖУВАТИ**](http://sum.in.ua/s/odruzhuvaty), ую, уєш, *недок[онаний вид]*, **ОДРУЖИ́ТИ**, одружу, одружиш, *док[онаний вид]*, *перех[ідне дієслово]*, *з ким, на кому і без додатка*. Єднати шлюбом чоловіка і жінку. <…>

Ну й ще додатково:

> [**ОДРУ́ЖУВАТИСЯ**](http://sum.in.ua/s/odruzhuvatysja), уюся, уєшся, *недок[онаний вид]*, **ОДРУЖИ́ТИ**, одружуся, одружишся, *док[онаний вид]*, *перех[ідне дієслово]*, *з ким, на кому і без додатка*. Брати шлюб. <…>

Поки що ніде не випливає, що це стосується лише однієї статі.

## Приклади з літератури щодо жіночої статі

З того ж словника:

> Було навіть приємно, що **Фрося одружена** саме з Циганком. Вони якраз підходять одне до одного (Олекса Гуреїв, Наша молодість, 1949, 321).
>
> **Одружили Палажку** з парубком, і, добре погулявши на весіллі, свекор забрав молодих та й повіз до себе (Олекса Стороженко, I, 1957, 27).
>
> **Софія одружувалась** з Ізаровим (Анатолій Шиян, Вибр., 1947, 5).

І ще додатково:

> — Невідомо. Встановити не вдалося. **Неодружена**. Квартира на Щорса, але вона там не живе, тільки прописана (Павло Загребельний «Попіл снів»).
>
> Найближчою моєю сусідкою з правого боку, була елеґантна, **неодружена**, горда міс років тридцяти з пишним червоним волоссям, яка носила завжди модні капелюхи і мала забавного, кудлатого, сірого йоркширського пуделя. <…> — Ви звичайно не курите, а може вже навчились? Ні. Зрештою, це не найкраща звичка. А як там після балю? Як там ваша русявка? О-о-о! Тіп-топ, що й казати, чому б не заручитися? Маєте хату...О! О! О! Вона вже **одружена**. Чому б не подумати про іншу русявку? <…> Налетіла також й Галина Дуб, також щасливо **одружена** з власником якоїсь майстерні і напевно нарешті вдоволена долею (Улас Самчук «На твердій землі»).
>
> А тим часом, поки що хай краще вона лишатиметься **неодруженою**, хай краще вона ціле життя своє проживе старою дівою, ніж поневірятись у шлюбі з такою хаотичною, непевною себе людиною (Віктор Петров (Домонтович) «Самотній мандрівник простує по самотній дорозі»).

А якщо шукати поза словником застосування всіх цих форм до жіночої статі (а не лише дієприкметника з *не-*), то бачимо, що просто безліч авторів їх уживають.